# Input impedance of op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, input-impedance

[image]

How can I calculate the input impedance of this circuit?

Comment: A simple practice seems like connecting a 1V sinusoidal source in place of V3 and measure the current flowing through it  Then (1/ Current) becomes input impedance. Dont know if  \$V_{cc}  or  V_{ee} \$ have to be disabled or not.

Comment: Thx for fast reply. How about using circuit analysis method, not using simulation??

Comment: No need for either; it's 100 kohm.

Comment: In circuit analysis methods,  You have to measure the current flowing through the input voltage source to measure \$ Z_{th} \$ . Assume your voltage source to be  a 1V RMS \$V_{th}\$.  I would probably use KVL equations with complex voltage and assume complex currents flowing through the feedback loops  in resistor and capcitor and calculate V/I in phasor  terms.

Comment: U1 pin 2 (the op-amp inverting input) is a virtual ground. Once you realize that, it is easy to figure out the input impedance, as Andy said.

Comment: Is the op-amp assumed to be ideal, or does the characteristics of the poor old 741 need to be taken into account?

Comment: @Justme op-amp assumed to be ideal. I used pspice just for drawing circuit,

Comment: If so, then it's very simple - what have you tried so far to figure it out? This is a simple homework question, you can just look it up. Use the ideal op-amp rules to figure it out.

Comment: For idea lop amp, the input terminals 2 and 3 in the diagram are shorted to ground. I just mentioned a very general method. So the input impedance is between \$V_{test}\$  and glround which is  R1. So, input impedance is 100 KΩ.

Comment: @AmitM: The input terminals are not shorted together for an ideal op-amp, even though their voltages are the same. That is why the term "virtual" is used.

Comment: Yes, it is virtual ground.

Comment: It is good practice to add a resistor from op-amp V+ to GND, to balance bias and offset currents. The value would be approximately that of R1 and R2 in parallel. That might affect the input impedance.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a test voltage *Vx* at the input node and calculate the current *Ix*. Then, *Vx/Ix* is the input impedance. It turns out to be *R1* in your case. You can approach such problems by setting V+ = V- (for an ideal op-amp).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a *real* op amp configured as an inverting (or transimpedance) amplifier (voltage sampling, shunt mixing), the input resistance will be highest when the negative feedback is lowest, say at a high frequency. As the frequency is reduced, the negative feedback will increase as the open loop gain increases which will have the effect of reducing the input impedance until it reaches a minimum of just about 100k at DC.

This is in contrast to a non-inverting amplifier (voltage sampling, series mixing) where the input resistance *increases* with increasing negative feedback, say as a result of reducing frequency.

For both types of amplifier, the output resistance increases with reducing negative feedback, say as a result of increasing frequency.